# How do I find a second order differential equation given its solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $y=Ae^x+Be^{-2x}-x$

Find $ay''(x)+by'(x)+cy=f(x)$

I have considered the auxiliary equation whose roots should be the exponents in the given equation: $k_1=1$ and $k_2=-2$. I believe that $f(x)=px+q$ given the additional $-x$ term but I don't know how to find the values of $a,b$ or $c$ for the differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know the roots $\lambda$ of the auxiliary equation and the order of the DE, which means $a\lambda^2 + b\lambda + c = 0$ has roots $1$ and $2$. Once you find $a, b, c$, $f(x)$ can be found by plugging $y = -x$ into $ay'' + by' + cy$.

Comment: Technically the problem is ambiguous since you can scale all coefficients and $f$ by the same constant and get another equation. But it is probably most convenient to just decide $a=1$.

Comment: @Ian I was leaving that part out for a follow up question lol